# Excel-VBA Count variable substrings in a string

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am using Excel VBA to validate the accuracy of a string. I need to make sure a variable substring is not duplicated. I have used a bulky ElseIf method, but it is missing instances where more than one substring was used. The first substring passed, but it does not loop back to check on the next substring.

```
Dim chkstring As String, phrase As String

If InStr(chkstring, "BAG") > 0 Then
        phrase = "BAG"
    ElseIf InStr(chkstring, "NOTE") > 0 Then
        phrase = "NOTE"
    ElseIf InStr(chkstring, "MEMO") > 0 Then
        phrase = "MEMO"
Else
        phrase = ""
    End If
If phrase <> "" Then
        OccurCount = findOccurancesCount(chkstring, phrase)
        If OccurCount > 1 Then
            'highlight cell
        End If
    End If
```

Then I use

```
Function findOccurancesCount(chkstring, phrase)
        OccurCount = 0
        y = 1
    Do
    foundPosition = InStr(y, chkstring, phrase) 'searching from i position
    If foundPosition > 0 Then                       'substring is found at foundPosition index
        OccurCount = OccurCount + 1       'count this occurance
        y = foundPosition + 1                       'searching from x+1 on the next cycle
    End If
    Loop While foundPosition <> 0
findOccurancesCount = OccurCount

End Function
```

This is fine if the chkstring = "BAG BAG"
But if there is more than one phrase it will not go back to look for others. 
For example: "BAG NOTE NOTE"

"BAG" passes the check, but it does not go back to look for "NOTE".

I am wondering if there is a more effective way to combine all of the possible phrases then check to see if any of them are in the chkstring more than one?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want for output?  Your question indicates you want to validate a string, which implies a simple binary response; but your code suggest you are looking for something different.

Comment: there is a binary aspect to it, but there are multiple variables. The pass is if any of the key substrings are only included once in the chkstring. The fail is if any of the key substrings are duplicated in the chkstring

Comment: Then, if you just want a `True` / `False` answer, the code I just undeleted will return `FALSE` if any substrings are repeated, else it will return `TRUE`.  If you are only looking for certain substrings, it can be easily modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count number of occurrences of a phrase in chkstring you can use this function

```
Function findOccurancesCount(chkstring, phrase)
    findOccurancesCount = (Len(chkstring) - Len(Replace(chkstring, phrase, ""))) / Len(phrase)
End Function
```

Then you can call like this, or some other way such as looping an array of phrases, depending on how many phrases you intend to check for:

```
Sub test(chkstring as String)
    If findOccurancesCount(chkstring, "BAG") > 1 _
        Or findOccurancesCount(chkstring, "NOTE") > 1 _
        Or findOccurancesCount(chkstring, "MEMO") > 1 _
        Then
        'highlight cell
        Debug.Print "highlight cell"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, also to check each phrase, change your `ElseIf` to individulal `If...End If` statements so each phrase is checked for. `ElseIf` will not be checked if a condition is matched earlier in the `If` chain

Comment: Thanks raysinnz, I think that will do it. I was probably trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be

Answer (score 0):

Try this function if you need something similar to what you already have

```
Function findOccurancesCount(chkstring, phrase)
 Dim residualString As String
 Dim OccurCount As Integer

 OccurCount = 0
 residualString = chkstring

 Do

    foundPosition = InStr(1, residualString, phrase)                            'search phrase in residualString
    If foundPosition > 0 Then                                                   'substring is found at foundPosition index
        OccurCount = OccurCount + 1                                             'count this occurance
        residualString = Replace(residualString, phrase, "", foundPosition, 1)  'remove found phrase from residualString
    End If
 Loop While foundPosition <> 0                                                   'loop until no phrase is found

 findOccurancesCount = OccurCount

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that uses Regular Expressions to see if any word in the string occurs more than once.

If there are no duplicate words --> `TRUE`, else `FALSE`

```
Option Explicit
Function noDups(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(\b\w+\b)(?=.*\1)"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    noDups = Not .test(s)
End With

End Function
```

[image]

If you are only looking for a few keywords to NOT be duplicated, then change the pattern:

```
eg:  sPat = "(\b(?:bag|note|memo)\b)(?=.*\1)"
```